# Spring Bean Not Found

Tags: java, spring

I have this project hierarchy:

A SpringConfiguration.java file with one Bean (SoapServiceBean).
A LoggerUtilsConfiguration.java with two beans (ConfigManager and LoggerManager).

SpringConfiguration imports LoggerUtilsConfigueration with an @Import.

The code:

```
@Configuration
@Import({com.myApp.LoggerUtilsConfiguration.class})
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = "soapServiceBean")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SoapServiceBean soapServiceBeanInit(
            @Qualifier("configManager") ConfigManager  configManager ,
            @Qualifier("loggerManager") LoggerManager loggerManager) 
            throws ServiceException, SystemException {

        SoapServiceBean service = new SoapServiceBean();
        service.setConfigManager(configManager);
        service.setLoggerManager(loggerManager);

        return service; 
    }

}

@Configuration
public class LoggerUtilsConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "configManager")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SINGLETON)
    public ConfigManager configManagerInit() {

        ConfigManager cManager = new ConfigManager();

        return cManager; 
    }

    @Bean(name = "loggerManager")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SINGLETON)
    public LoggerManager loggerManagerInit() {

        LoggerManager cManager = new LoggerManager();

        return cManager; 
    }

}
```

My problema is that, "configManager" is a valid bean, but loggerManager throws this Exception:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.myApp.LoggerManager] found for dependency: 
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
    Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=loggerManager)}
```

Is very Strange, because If I copy the loggerManager Bean method into the main @Configuration class, the app starts with no problem and loggerManager is started with no problem.

"LoggerUtilsConfiguration" is not part of my App, is a Maven dependency external jar from another dev team. I have decompiled it and I cannot see anything strange, "configManager" and "loggerManager" has the same annotations with the same values except the bean name.

Any idea?

Comment: Try autowire instead of passing the attributes as parameters. Autowire them with qualifier annotation. Also put @Component.

Comment: I can only guess that LoggerUtilsConfiguration is not autoscanned. Yo can try to delay bean injections using field injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

My problem is the WebSphere, that store an old version of the third party JAR.

```
\was\wasprofiles\wp_profile80\installedApps\GUUPZN00Cell\MY-APP.ear\lib\LOGGER-LIB-1.0.0.jar
\was\wasprofiles\wp_profile80\installedApps\GUUPZN00Cell\MY-APP.ear\lib\LOGGER-LIB-1.0.1.jar
```

The version "1.0.0" LOGGER-LIB doesn't  contains the bean "loggerManager" and WebSphere is loading this version of the library.
It seems that the file was blocked when websphere try to delete it. I had to stop the server to delete it properly.

Comment: You should accept you own answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I know but I can't until tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 managers are singletons you can `@Autowired` them in.

If there is an existing bean called `loggerManager` of a different type then it wouldn't find yours, but it depends on how your classpath is set up.

```
@Configuration
@Import({com.myApp.LoggerUtilsConfiguration.class})
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ConfigManager configManager;
    @Autowired
    LoggerManager loggerManager;

    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = "soapServiceBean")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SoapServiceBean soapServiceBeanInit() 
            throws ServiceException, SystemException {

        SoapServiceBean service = new SoapServiceBean();
        service.setConfigManager(configManager);
        service.setLoggerManager(loggerManager);

        return service; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [@DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html):

```
    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = "soapServiceBean")
    @DependsOn({ "configManager", "loggerManager" })
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SoapServiceBean soapServiceBeanInit(
            @Qualifier("configManager") ConfigManager  configManager ,
            @Qualifier("loggerManager") LoggerManager loggerManager) 
            throws ServiceException, SystemException {

        SoapServiceBean service = new SoapServiceBean();
        service.setConfigManager(configManager);
        service.setLoggerManager(loggerManager);

        return service; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing autowire annotation to properly enable constructor injection like :

```
@Configuration
@Import({com.myApp.LoggerUtilsConfiguration.class})
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "soapServiceBean")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SoapServiceBean soapServiceBeanInit(
            @Qualifier("configManager") ConfigManager  configManager ,
            @Qualifier("loggerManager") LoggerManager loggerManager) 
            throws ServiceException, SystemException {

        SoapServiceBean service = new SoapServiceBean();
        service.setConfigManager(configManager);
        service.setLoggerManager(loggerManager);

        return service; 
    }

}
```

The `@Qualifier` annotation is used to resolve the bean based on names while the `@Autowired` annotation provides constructor injection of beans. The `@Bean` annotation should support constructor injection without the need for `@Autowired`

Comment: No, thats no the solution.